# How many answers are needed to establish a Schelling focal point?

Tags: estimation, econometrics, survey

Consider Schelling's question about a focal meeting point for NYC in game theory (described in the second paragraph under **Formulation** in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_point_(game_theory))).  Schelling didn't say how many students he surveyed. How many students does he have to interview to be 95% sure that the mode is the population's mode, assuming that students are representative of the population?

Comment: Right, we're trying to solve for the general case... Any pointers towards papers / solution paths would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's only one game structure, however the number of distinct categorical answers is unlimited... This seems like empiric distribution applied to categorical data.

Comment: OK, that should provide the needed context, thanks.